# Does every command have a possible response?

Tags: spaceteam

When a command appears at the top of a player's screen in Spaceteam, is it guaranteed that one of the players will have a button/switch/dial that allows them to fulfill the command? Or are there sometimes "trick commands" that no one can accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every command issued can be completed. One pitfall that new players fall into is assuming that the commands are only for other players. It's entirely possible that a command may be for your own panel!